# Failure import pygame in IDE on python 3.8.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-import, wing-ide

I have downloaded pygame:

```
C:\>pip3 install pygame --user

Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\mpenn\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (2.0.0.dev8)
```

And I have python 3.8.3:

```
C:\>py
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

But when I try to import pygame in my "Wing Personal 7" IDE, I get the error:

```
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

This has only started happening since I updated python to 3.8.3 yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

make sure your python directory(the one where all the modules are stored) is added to the PATH variable. There are already many tutorials to do so:

[How do I add Python to the Windows PATH](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path)

or if that doesn't work for you, google is your best friend.

Answer (score 1):

In Wing, you need to change python executable to the python version you are using.  python executable is found in Project, Project Properties...

Comment: Did this solve it?  In general, setting Python Executable in Project Properties to the value of sys.executable in the Python you want to use will solve issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that pip is up to date. Try running:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```